# Trying to wire up a jQuery .click() event .. but it's getting fired (instead of just wiring up)

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, click

So i have the following jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // Init.
    $(function () {

        // Wire up the search box.
        $('#searchButton').click(
            search($('#query').val(),
                $('aaa').val(),
                $('bbb').val()
            ));
    });

</script>
```

But when i first hit the page, the `search` function is getting fired (because I put a breakpoint in there).

I thought my code (above) is just saying: *Wire up the click event AND when someone clicks that button, the following code is called => search function with the following 3 arguments)*.

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong, please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because it expects a function reference. What you're doing is executing search() and passing that result as the reference.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // Init.
    $(function () {

        // Wire up the search box.
        $('#searchButton').click(function() {
                search($('#query').val(),
                    $('aaa').val(),
                    $('bbb').val()
                ));
            }
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

You should wrap your handler code inside an anonymous function.

Otherwise *search()* will get evaluated and the result will be applied to the click handler.

Try this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#searchButton').click(function () {
        search( $('#query').val(),
                $('aaa').val(),
                $('bbb').val() 
        );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are calling function "click" with one parameter, the return of "search(); and it is not a function callback.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // Init.
    $(function () {

        // Wire up the search box.
        $('#searchButton').click(function() {
            search($('#query').val(),
                $('aaa').val(),
                $('bbb').val()); }
            );
    });

</script>
```

Attach anonymous function on click event, 
and call `search($('#query').val(),$('aaa').val(),$('bbb').val());` in function.

Answer (score -3):

```
    $('#searchButton').live('click',function() {
        whatever...
    });
```

Comment: This doesn't address the actual problem, and `.live()` is deprecated.